# Undefined variable error within Login script

Tags: php, pdo

This is a section below of my login script:

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$salt = "$2a$10$R.Baj0mvj5doNvtvzDjwP5$";

$crypt_pass=crypt($password,$salt);

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Consultants WHERE email = :email');

$query->bindParam(":email",$email);

$results = $query->execute();

$total = $query->rowCount();
$row = $query->fetch();
```

The error:

> "PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: R in /Users/Sites/pages/login.php on line 6" This is the line of which the error occurs - $salt = "$2a$10$R.Baj0mvj5doNvtvzDjwP5$";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dollar signs are being interpreted as variables. You either need to escape them:

```
$salt = "\$2a\$10\$R.Baj0mvj5doNvtvzDjwP5\$";
```

or use single quotes:

```
$salt = '$2a$10$R.Baj0mvj5doNvtvzDjwP5$';
```

The reason why the 'R' is being singled out is variables names that start with numbers are not valid in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes. With the double-quotes, PHP is attempting to interpolate the variable names. Single quotes will prevent this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using double quotes, it's trying to parse variables inside the string. use single quotes like this.

```
$salt = '$2a$10$R.Baj0mvj5doNvtvzDjwP5$';
```